# How to string formatting a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Here is my script:

```
# I have 100 variables
x0 = 3.14
x1 = 2.72
x2 = 1.41
x3 = 2.33
.... (omit this part)
x100 = 7.77

# xi corresponds to the value that the index i of a list needs to subtract, 
# now I want to loop through the list
for i in range(100):
    lst[i] -= 'x{}'.format(i)
```

This clearly won't work, since the variable is not a string. So how should I string formatting a variable?

Comment: You should seriously rethink your design. Why having 100 variables, when you can have a single variable referring to a list and access each value by index? Even if it's generated code, then better generate a list!

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But this is an over-simplified version. In my real case, I need to use this string-formatting (if possible) trick to avoid an additional for loop. If there are better solutions, I would not ask this question.

Comment: Yes, you can be sure there are better solutions. And what's wrong with having an additional `for` if it helps you avoid having 100 variables? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you're asking something to get around a problem, but the real issue is different - and we don't know all of the context to be able to effectively help you.

Comment: I understand this may look like an XY problem, but I am acutually a computational chemist and I am using some Python packages particularly for my field. It doesn't make any sense if I put my actual script here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access these variables using [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#locals):

```
lst[i] -= locals()['x{}'.format(i)]
```

Comment: This ```locals()``` function works fine. I will accept your answer since your answer is not finding another way around and don't use ```eval()``` which seems to be a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead use a `list` here.

`x = [...]` (where `x` has a `len` of 100)

Then for your loop:

```
for i in range(100):
    lst[i] -= x[i]
```

(Renamed `list` to `lst` to avoid name collision with the built-in type)

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for. This script is oversimplified, and for my real case, the ```x1``` to ```x100``` are also all variables, and is generated on-the-fly. So basically my purpose is to update the ```list[i]``` AS SOON AS the ```xi``` is generated.

Comment: if the variables are dynamically generated and assigned, and you want to update `list[i]` as soon as the corresponding x value is generated, you should look into using iterators or generators. Point is, having this many variables when you could have just one containing/generating all the values is going to be very hard to maintain.

Comment: The OP is asking for a technique to solve their specific problem. @Arhiliuc Cristina gave a good answer. Whether using ‘eval()‘ is a good idea is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value of the variable, you can use Python's [eval function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```
eval('x{}'.format(i))
```

And please, don't ever call your list variable list.

**Edit:** While this solution works in this case, it is recommended to avoid eval as much as possible because it allows code injections in a way you wouldn't expect.

Comment: [Why using `eval()` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).